# file_put_contents permission inside Docker

Tags: php, docker

I'm having issues on write files inside a docker container. Always receiving a permission denied message.

I already tried using the following inside Dockerfile but any of them worked.

```
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/folder
```

or

```
RUN chmod 775 -R /var/www/html/folder
```

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your webserver is configured to run as the user 'www-data'?

Comment: I am experiencing this as well. Strange is that this happens only on my server (Ubuntu) and not locally (macOS). `docker version` says that bot machines are running the same docker version. File permissions are set.

Answer (score 0):

Either the path does not exist when the image is being built or the user www-data does not exist.

If 'docker build' is failing, it will show you what the error is.

If the image is built, fire up a container and exec into it, see what the permissions are and run the command from the command line:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash
id www-data
ls -l /var/www/html/folder
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/folder
```

This should reveal what the issue is and what changes need to be made to Dockerfile.

In addition, if that chmod occurs BEFORE the user is created in your Dockerfile (due to apache install for instance), the chmod will need to go after web server is installed